# I would like to use a dollar sign in a flutter, how can I do this?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to use a dollar sign in a flutter, how can I do this?

like this:

```
Text('$21.99')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Escape Sequence Character,

```
Text('\$21.99')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use raw string by suffixing `r`.

Like this

```
Text(r'$21.99')
```